# When multiple user accessing Data through UI, Heap memory got filled and application report out of memory error

Tags: hibernate, exception, websphere, heap-memory, production-environment

Hi guys I am working with ***Domain specific language(DSL)*** and ***WebSphere***. My core is based on java, ***spring and Hibernate***. While multiple user try to fetch data from Database at a same time through UI, Heap memory got filled and application report out of memory error.This issue occurring in Production environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *might* be able to resolve your issue by increasing the maximum JVM Heap Size configured on your server. To change the JVM Heap Size, navigate to `Servers > WebSphere Application Servers > [server_name] > Java and process management > Process definition > Java virtual machine`. Adjust the minimum and maximum values for Heap Size and restart your server for the changes to take effect.

Please be aware that tuning your JVM is a highly complex process. You can use the information at [this IBM Documentation link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/container_tune_jvm.html) as a starting point.

To identify why your application is throwing an OOM error, you will have to perform some form of analysis. To do this, you need to simulate the expected production load on a different testing environment. Then you can collect PMI statistics, Javacores, Heap dumps, Core dumps and use them to identify why your applications encounter an OOM error.

Comment: @xsurgent- This is a simple way to increase heap size. We have  5GB space for heap memory.

Comment: See [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html) for the types of OOM Error. Can you cross-check with your stack trace and update the question with this information?